# Z Offset Keeps Changing Flashforge Hunter

Tags: z-axis, build-plate, flashforge

I am a newbie and I started having printing problems with my Flashforge Hunter.
I found out that with every calibration the building plate Z offset is getting larger by approx 0.1 mm to 0.2 mm, currently it is at 1.15 mm, first calibration it was 0.1 mm than it increased every few prints.
Really hope this is not a hardware problem. I was searching online for hours and couldn't find anything related to Z offset problem in resin printers.
Please help, I think the printing problem is because of this.